# Matplotlib inline animation stops on chrome

Tags: python, google-chrome, matplotlib, animation, inline

I've been using matplotlib animation figures for a long time, however, it stops working after moving the chrome window to another monitor. It simply erase all figures.

Second, after a while i'm away from computer -mostly after work hours- then, it stops updating but running (saving data) in background. This could be because of the new update of chrome that i have never seen anything like this before.

Is there anything that i can do to keep running animation for both situations?

I though it could be because of the plugging in/out monitor, but it seems irrelevant

So, i changed chrome settings to 'not go idle when afk' and it solved my second problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: When I move the chrome window from the laptop screen to the monitor screen, matplotlib inline graphics vanishes, showing a clear page instead of figures. Second, when I'm afk for a time, matplotlib inline stops updating figures but runs in the background. I don't know how to tell more clearly than that.